# How to pass onchange value from form:select into controller

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I am using **Spring MVC** for developing the Java Web Application.

In my current scenario, i am stuck in one situation.

In my current project, I have a dropdown and i need to pass the selected value on **onChange** to controller for processing the result.

For showing dropdown i am using form:select (Spring Form).

Can you please suggest me how to pass selected value to controller on **OnChange**

```
<body>
<form:form method="post" modelAttribute="ad" action="/save">
    <form:select cssClass="select" cssStyle="width:100%;margin-left:10%;"
        path="work_type" items="${allworktype}" itemValue="id"
        itemLabel="work_type" />
</form:form>
```

```
    @Controller
public class WebController {

    @Autowired
    public AdminBuildingRepo adminBuildingRepo;

    @ModelAttribute("allworktype")
    public List<AdminBuilding> getblocks(Model model){
    return  adminBuildingRepo.findAll();
    }


    @GetMapping("/")
    public String home(Model model) {
        AdminBuilding ad= new AdminBuilding();
        model.addAttribute("ad", ad);
        return "index";
    }



    @RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String transferForDevice( Model model) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("*********");
        //so now I can use "user" from @ModelAttribute
        return "redirect:/admin";
}

}
```

- Please help me how to pass value to controller on selection.

Answer (score 0):

```
function formSubmit(){ 

  $('form#myForm').attr({action: 'save'});  
  $('form#myForm').attr({modelAttribute: 'ad'});  
  $('form#myForm').attr({method: 'post'});    
  $('form#myForm').submit();
 }
```

declare form with id myForm
call this function on select onchange